# Using a C++ Class in Ada95 / Constructors and Controlled Types

Tags: c++, constructor, ada

Using a C++ Class in Ada95 / Constructors and Controlled Types

I would like to be able to use a C++ class in my Ada code. My goal is to keep my
Ada code portable to the Ada95 specification. I don't want to use any of the 
GNAT  or Ada05 specific methodologies.

I am using pragma Import (C) with wrapper functions in C to achieve my 
interfaces. But I am having trouble figuring out how to get my C++ Ctors/Dtors
to get called automatically. My first thought was to use Ada Controlled Types
and the Initialize would call the Ctor and Finalize would call the Dtor. This 
was all fine and good until I had a Ctor that needed me to pass parameters.

**Foo.h**

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(long x, long y, long z);
    Foo(const Foo& that);
    ~Foo();

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& that);

    long getX() const;
    long getY() const;
    long getZ() const;

    void setX(long x);
    void setY(long y);
    void setZ(long z);

private:
    long mX;
    long mY;
    long mZ;    
};
```

**Foo_Exports.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <new>

extern "C"
{
    void extFoo_New    (Foo* foo) { new (foo) Foo(); }  
    void extFoo_NewXYZ (Foo* foo, long x, long y, long z)   { new (foo) Foo(x,y,z); }
    void extFoo_Delete (Foo* foo) { foo->~Foo(); }  

    long extFoo_getX(const Foo& foo) { return foo.getX(); }
    long extFoo_getY(const Foo& foo) { return foo.getY(); }
    long extFoo_getZ(const Foo& foo) { return foo.getZ(); }

    void extFoo_setX(const Foo& foo, long x) { foo.setX(x) };
    void extFoo_setY(const Foo& foo, long y) { foo.setY(y) };
    void extFoo_setZ(const Foo& foo, long z) { foo.setZ(z) };
}
```

**cpp.foo.ads**

```
with Ada.Finalization;
with Interfaces.C;
use Interfaces.C;

package Cpp.Foo is

    type Obj_t is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled_Type with private;

    procedure Initialize (This : in out Obj_T);
    procedure Adjust     (This : in out Obj_T);
    procedure Finalize   (This : in out Obj_T);

    function Get_X (This : access Obj_T) return Long;
    function Get_Y (This : access Obj_T) return Long;
    function Get_Z (This : access Obj_T) return Long;

    procedure Set_X(This : access Obj_T; 
                    X    : in     Long );
    procedure Set_Y(This : access Obj_T; 
                    Y    : in     Long );
    procedure Set_Z(This : access Obj_T; 
                    Z    : in     Long );

private
    type Obj_t is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled_Type with null record;
    for Obj_T'Size use 192;
    for Obj_T'Alignment use 8;

    pragma Import (C, Get_X, "extFoo_getX");
    pragma Import (C, Get_Y, "extFoo_getY");
    pragma Import (C, Get_Z, "extFoo_getZ");

    pragma Import (C, Set_X, "extFoo_setX");
    pragma Import (C, Set_Y, "extFoo_setY");
    pragma Import (C, Set_Z, "extFoo_setZ");
end Cpp.Foo;
```

**cpp.foo.adb**

```
with System;

package body Cpp.Foo is

    procedure Initialize (This : in out Obj_T) is
        procedure ExtFoo_New(Addr : in System.Address);
        pragma Import (C, ExtFoo_New "extFoo_New");

        procedure ExtFoo_NewXYZ(Addr  : in System.Address,
                                X     : in Long;
                                Y     : in Long;
                                Z     : in Long);
        pragma Import (C, ExtFoo_NewXYZ "extFoo_NewXYZ");
    begin

        null; -- **WHAT DO I DO HERE?!**

    end Initialize;

    procedure Adjust     (This : in out Obj_T) is
    begin
        null; -- TBD copy ctor
    end Adjust;

    procedure Finalize   (This : in out Obj_T) is
        procedure ExtFoo_Delete(Addr : in System.Address);
        pragma Import (C, ExtFoo_Delete, extFoo_Delete);
    begin
        ExtFoo_Delete(This'address);
    end Finalize;


end Cpp.Foo;
```

Comment: Obj_t needs to keep some record of the C++ constructor’s return value (why are you specifying ‘Size and ‘Alignment?); I don’t believe you can fool Ada and C(++) into using the same area of memory for both. Initialize is only called on default initialization, and would call ExtFoo_New. You need another Ada subprogram (function, I expect) to call ExtFoo_NewXYZ.

Comment: @SimonWright I am using the 'Size and the 'Alignment so that I can allocate the correct amount of data on the stack when I declare a new Obj_T. You can fool Ada into using C++ memory by using the representation clause for 'Address [for Obj'Address use addr;] and You can do the same thing in C++ using placement new syntax [Foo* foo = new (addr) Foo();]. -- If I create another subprogram to call ExtFoo_NewXYZ, how do I get it to be called automatically? I want my Ada interface to look like Ada code, not look like an Ada interface for C++ code.

Comment: @Jerunh: What about using Swig (http://www.swig.org/)?

Comment: @wilx According to the Swig webpage, Ada is not listed as a language under compatibility.

Comment: @Jerunh: Ah, sorry. I was convinced it was there.

Comment: But where do you think Ada will put the information it needs to manage finalization? (with GNAT it would be two pointers before the first named component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Initialize` will only be called for default initialization:

```
O : Obj_t;
```

and is the subprogram that should call `ExtFoo_New`. In order to create an `Obj_t` with initial values, you need another function to call `ExtFoo_NewXYZ`, perhaps

```
function Create (X, Y, Z : Long_Integer) return Obj_T;
```

and then

```
O : Obj_T := Create (41, 42, 43);
```

That said, I really don’t think your scheme of overlaying the Ada `Obj_t` and the C++ `Foo` is a good idea, because both languages are entitled to use hidden fields. I can imagine that C++ might store a pointer to a dispatch table, and I know for certain that (in GNAT) a child of `Ada.Finalization.Controlled` contains links that implement a finalization chain. Other compilers may well do it a different way (and GNAT changed its strategy in GCC 4.7). So I would have `Obj_t` contain a reference to the C++ object (that is, the value returned by `Foo()`).

Comment: I ended up using the Create methodology combined with Controlled types so that I could use Adjust for copy constructor and Finalize for the Destructor. It's not as elegant as I would have hoped for, but it was the best solution that is available.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't any portable (language standard) way to call C++ class methods from within Ada 95. This goes for C, Fortran, and most any other major compiled system's programming language you might occasionally want to interface with C++.

To deal with this, you have to use the same techniques you'd typically use to deal with it when interfacing to a C program. Basically, anything that needs to be called from the other language must have a C-linkable C++ function associated with it. In C++ that typically means either a naked function, or a static member function, with `extern "C"` applied to it.

Gnat, due to its tight integration with GCC, has some better facilities for dealing with C++ code. However, that isn't standard.

Note that its possible to "bootstrap" such a non-OO call into an OO method call by passing the object as its parameter, then having the non-OO call make the appropriate method call on that object. Still, that means you need one such bootstrapping function for each method.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't this exactly what I did in Foo_Exports.cpp? I wrapped all my OO calls in naked functions and passed the object in as a parameter. My question is really what do I do inside my Initialize function to determine which Constructor call I should make, and How do I get the Data to the Constructor call?

Answer (score 0):

I've extended your code sample and uploaded it to a [repo on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/OCTAGRAM/cpp-in-ada-example)

It contains ctor wrapper including default constructor, copy constructor and custom constructor. I've added some code to provide debug output. From what I can see everything works as expected, but Create (custom ctor wrapper) causes two redundant hops of copy/delete.

```
Foo()
Foo(long, long, long)
Foo(const Foo&)
~Foo()
Foo(const Foo&)
~Foo()
Foo()
Foo(const Foo&)
Uninitialized A, should be   0   0   0:    0   0   0
Initialized B,   should be   4   5   6:    4   5   6
Copied B to C,   should be   4   5   6:    4   5   6
Modified C,      should be   4   7   6:    4   7   6
~Foo()
Foo(const Foo&)
Copied C to A,   should be   4   7   6:    4   7   6
~Foo()
~Foo()
~Foo()
~Foo()
```

My wrappers rely on the assumption that it's safe to move object contents around and invoke copy constructor from a bitwise copied object contents as opposed to copying from a genuine object created by a real constructor.

This approach won't work in rare cases when C++ object locations in memory are tracked somehow. Adjust.Temp_Copy will be unaccounted orphan this way.

Flat_Get_X uses System.Address instead of access because access constant Argument is a feature of Ada 2005 and plain access is not available for read-only This.